# return value from observable to view problem

Tags: javascript, angular, data-binding, observable, nativescript

I am working on image upload with `nativescript`, but I couldn't return the image `base64` to my view for the preview, the problem here is my function does not read my global variable.

here is the code

```
myImg:any;
pickFiles() {
let options = {
  title: "Importer",
  cancelButtonText: "Annuler",
  actions: ["Image(s)", "Video(s)", "Audio(s)", "Fichier(s)"]
};
dialogs.action(options).then(async (result) => {
  if (result == 'Image(s)') {...}
  if (result == 'Video(s)') {...}
  if (result == 'Audio(s)') {...}
  if (result == 'Fichier(s)') {...}
  this.mdf.on("getFiles", async function (res: any) {
    let results = res.object.get('results');
    let img1 = await imageSourceModule.fromFile(results[0].file).toBase64String('jpg');
    // let img2 = await imageSourceModule.fromBase64(img1)
   this.myImg;
  });
  this.mdf.on("error", function (res) {
    let msg = res.object.get('msg');
    console.log(msg);
  });
});
```

I expect that the variable `myImg` gets the new value of the `img`, but when I bind it to view it becomes null.

Comment: `this.myImg;` how do you expect this to assign the new value?.. `this.myImg = img1;` is likely what you're looking for. Also, remove `function` and replace it with a lambda, otherwise the `this` will be scoped.

Comment: yea exactly but he is not getting it as a global variable, when i click with ctrl +click it won't go back to global variable ( vs code) and when i tried to give it  a simple string in constructor and change it in this function it's not changing

Comment: If it's not assigning it, its `this` is incorrect because wrapped in a `function` block. Can you please show more code to work with?

Comment: `export class NvPubComponent implements OnInit {
  type; objectif; submitted; myImg;
  mdf = new Mediafilepicker();
pickFiles(){
}`
that's my class

Comment: Ok, so it's just enough to replace the `async function (res: any)` with: `(res: any)` (converting it to a lambda) and to assign `this.myImg` to `img1`. Using the lambda, the `this` inside it will be the class's `this` (in this case, the component's this)

Comment: it assigning it now but didn't change it's content

Comment: You seem to be using Promises not Observable which should be still fine. Can you share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced?

Comment: now i ve resole some problem and still one , i cound't make the variable this.myImg get the value of img1 and bind it to view, when i try to console.log it show me the new value ( img1 value) but when i bind it it keep the old valu ( null)

Answer (score 0):

`myImg1` which you are referring from an anonymous function will not be referenced and you must be getting an error on console. The reason is anonymous function will have it;s own `this` and will not refer to the `this` of component. So you need to have an arrow function:

You need to modify you code like this:

```
pickFiles() {
let options = {
  title: "Importer",
  cancelButtonText: "Annuler",
  actions: ["Image(s)", "Video(s)", "Audio(s)", "Fichier(s)"]
};
dialogs.action(options).then(async (result) => {
  if (result == 'Image(s)') {...}
  if (result == 'Video(s)') {...}
  if (result == 'Audio(s)') {...}
  if (result == 'Fichier(s)') {...}
  this.mdf.on("getFiles", async (res: any) => {
    let results = res.object.get('results');
    let img1 = await imageSourceModule.fromFile(results[0].file).toBase64String('jpg');
    // let img2 = await imageSourceModule.fromBase64(img1)
    this.myImg = img1;
  });
  this.mdf.on("error", function (res) {
    let msg = res.object.get('msg');
    console.log(msg);
  });
});
```

Comment: it was like so but it's not working too and this is strange, even like so when i click this.myImg is not going back to global variable

Comment: put a console there and try to print myImg what so you see?

Comment: it print it but when i call it again with other function it show null